# Android Studio Can't Startup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, startup

Android studio was working correctly until I restore default setting from
**File->Manage IDE Settings->Restore Default Setting**, Then I can't startup it again.

Every time I run Android studio I got this error

[image]

I tried to uninstall it and remove settings and SDK then install it again but also it didn't work

This is The error

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator' [Plugin: com.intellij]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1739)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:218)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:325)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:133)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:189)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator' [Plugin: com.intellij]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError$intellij_platform_serviceContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:423)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:60)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstanceUncached(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:110)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:64)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.BaseComponentAdapter.getInstance$default(BaseComponentAdapter.kt:57)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:340)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$loadComponents$5(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.loadComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:348)
    at com.intellij.idea.ApplicationLoader$startApp$6$loadComponentInEdtFuture$1.run(ApplicationLoader.kt:198)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/kapt/idea/KaptProjectResolverExtension
    at com.android.tools.idea.projectsystem.gradle.DisableKaptProjectResolverExtensionInitializer.run(DisableKaptProjectResolverExtensionInitializer.kt:24)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ConstructorInjectionKt.instantiateUsingPicoContainer(constructorInjection.kt:52)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClassWithConstructorInjection(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:771)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.MyComponentAdapter.doCreateInstance(MyComponentAdapter.kt:35)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt.idea.KaptProjectResolverExtension PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android, version=2021.1.1 Patch 2, package=null), packagePrefix=null, instanceId=50, state=active)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 46 more

-----
Your JRE: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

Can Anyone Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by deleting a file **AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudioxxxx.x** Then uninstall Android studio and install it again